# To test for uniform convergence of the following function

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

So, the function is given to be $[\cos (\pi n!x)]^{2n}$ and we have to check for uniform convergence in $[0,1]$. 
I am facing problem in finding the pointwise limit of the function. For $x=0$, it will be $1$. What the limit would be for other cases?

Comment: If $x=p/q$ is rational, then, for $n\geq q$ you have that $n!x$ is an integer. Therefore the pointwise limit for rational $x$ is $1$, I'd say. I'm not sure what happens when $x$ is irrational.